# Getting complete event on HIDE Jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

I have the following code:

```
$("#div_1").hide("slide", 
        { direction: "left" }, 
        5000);
```

How can I get the complete event after the sliding is done?

Thx

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hide/ .... its really that simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#div_1").hide("slide", 
        { direction: "left" }, 
        5000, function() { // code that will be executed on completion

});
```